# Issue with data array format

Tags: wp-query, database

I am trying to fetch a record of date from table `booking_history` with bellow code but the result array not displaying any record from `start_date` column. 
when i echo the query query  displaying value accurately.

```
$booking_date = $_POST['booking_date'];

$post_id = $_POST['post_id'];

echo $check_cust_query = "SELECT start_date FROM `".$wpdb->prefix."booking_history`
                        WHERE start_date='".$booking_date."'
                        AND post_id='".$post_id."'";

                 $results_check_cust = $wpdb->get_results ($check_cust_query);
                print_r ($results_check_cust);
                foreach ( $results_check_cust as $key => $value )
                    { 
                      $date= $value->start_date;
                      echo  $date;
                    }
```

Bellow is table structure [image: table]

Comment: If you already know the `$current_date`, then why to retrieve it from the db table ? Can you post a row of data from the table, and a sample `$current_date` ?

Comment: i have added table snip in post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks good though. But Try the following approach -

```
$current_date = $_POST['current_date'];
$current_date = date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime($current_date) );

$post_id = (int) $_POST['post_id'];

$query = $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT start_date FROM {$wpdb->prefix}booking_history WHERE start_date=%s AND post_id=%d", $current_date, $post_id );
/* get_col used to retrieve column records */
$results = $wpdb->get_col( $query );

echo '<pre>'; print_r( $results ); echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: getting array blank

Comment: An example of `echo $current_date;` ?

Comment: not understand what you try to saying

Comment: A value of `$current_date`. If yet confusing, put `echo $current_date;` at the end of the code of my answer, and let me know what do you see after the blank array.

Comment: It is displaying current date

Comment: i have to cross very fey with db current entered date have any same date in da table.

Comment: "It is displaying current date" - what is the date value ?

Comment: it is like 13-9-2014

Comment: current date value is booking date value of user it is not current date it will be anything like 15-09-2014

Comment: This is working how can add where clause to seprate out array value

Comment: global $wpdb;
 $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "plugin_table";
 $active_rows = $wpdb->get_results(
  "SELECT * FROM {$table_name}"
 );

 foreach ($active_rows as $active_row){
  echo $active_row->the_title;
 }

Comment: Answer edited. Problem was with your compared and database date format. Should work now.

Comment: its working but i am not able to store array in simple variable using foreach

Comment: got it nice answer